# Detecting dynamically loaded classes in a java program

Tags: java, reflection, instrumentation, soot

I am using soot to instrument classes of an application. But I've found to way to instrument classes dynamically with it. Soot only detect static links which would cause failures with programs with dynamic loading. So I have to detect what classes are dynamically loaded in a program. Suppose I don't have the option to instrument all classes for practical reasons. For example, I have to instrument the whole JDK that could take hours. Because there is the possibility that a JDK class is loaded at run time.
My ultimate goal from this tool/method is to give me the complete name of all classes that a program uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People usually use TamiFlex in combination with Soot for such issues:
https://code.google.com/p/tamiflex/

TamiFlex lets you record dynamic loading with very little overhead.